# LINQ Repository & method return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, repository-pattern

I am new to C#, MVC, LINQ, Entity Framework, and everything else I'm doing.  I have picked the stackoverflow brain-trust and other sites on this issue and do not see how to resolve it.

I am trying to implement the Repository pattern for a new application we are building and having problems returning the query results.  The first and most pressing issue is that I am getting the error below, and the second is more a matter of figuring out how to handle empty results from the query.

For this issue, I am trying to get a list of requests from the database to be presented in the dashboard view.  We have a working prototype that uses SQL queries, and I'm trying to replace it with repositories, which may be overkill, but it is something we feel we want to do.

Here is the view:

```
@using RAM.DAL.Models
@model RequestViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
} 

<h1>Dashboard</h1>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Resource Requests</h2>
        <div class="panel">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-primary">
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Mission Title</th>
                        <th>Resource Requested</th>
                        <th>Person</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if (Model.isEmpty)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">No requests pending</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <tr onclick="location.href= '@Url.Action("Assignment", "Mission", new { id = Model.ID })'">
                            <td>@Model.ID</td>
                            <td>@Model.title</td>
                            <td>@Model.resourceTitle</td>
                            <td>@Model.userName</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
    <!--<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Content 1 Btn &raquo;</a></p>-->
</div>
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
using System;

namespace RAM.DAL.Models
{
    public class RequestViewModel
    {
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string requestText { get; set; }
        public string user_ID { get; set; } //The userID of the user being requested.
        public string userName { get; set; } //Full name of the user being requested
        public int? fromResourceID { get; set; } //The resource where the request was generated from
        public int? toResourceID { get; set; } //The resource where the reassigned worker is requested to go to
        public string resourceTitle { get; set; } //Title of the resource where the reassigned worker is requested to go to
        public DateTime? requestDate { get; set; }//The date the request was made
        public bool? isEmpty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the repository up to the GetRequests method I'm having problems with (the rest is not implemented yet):

```
using RAM.DAL.Models;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RAM.DAL
{
    public class RequestRepository : IRequestRepository<RequestViewModel>
    {

        private RAMcontext context;

        public RequestRepository(RAMcontext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<RequestViewModel> GetRequests()
        {
            var requests = from r in context.RAM_Requests
                    join u in context.Users on r.user_ID equals u.User_ID
                    join res in context.RAM_Resources on r.toResourceID equals res.ID
                    where r.resolved == false
                    select new RequestViewModel()
                    {
                        title = r.title,
                        ID = r.ID,
                        fromResourceID = r.fromResourceID,
                        toResourceID = r.toResourceID,
                        user_ID = r.user_ID,
                        userName = u.First_Name + " " + u.Last_Name,
                        resourceTitle = res.title,
                        requestText = r.requestText,
                        requestDate = r.requestDate
                     };
            /*   }
              catch
              {

               RequestViewModel empty = new RequestViewModel
                  {
                      isEmpty = true
                  };
               return empty;
              }*/
            return requests.ToList().AsEnumerable();
        }
```

The error I'm getting is:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RAM.DAL.Models.RequestViewModel]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'RAM.DAL.Models.RequestViewModel'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, I guess your action method is sending a collection of `RequestViewModel` to the view. But your view is strongly typed to a single instance of `RequestViewModel` , not a collection. That is the reason you are getting this error.

Since you want to show a collection of requests, you should change the view to be strongly typed to a collection. You can use the LINQ `Any()` method to determine whether you have more than one item in the collection passed to the view and show/hide a message/ table to display the data.

```
@model IEnumerable<RequestViewModel>
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
@if(!Model.Any())
{
  <p>No records found </p>
}
else
{
  <table>
     <tr>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>User name </th>
     </tr>
  @foreach(var req in Model)
  {
     <tr>
         <td>@req.title</td>
         <td>@req.userName</td>
     </tr>
  }
  </table>
}
```

Comment: Actually, the if should be @if (!(Model.Any())).  And thanks for the clear answer.